# Elasticsearch sum first occurences of a day by term

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to convert our MySQL statistic Queries to our new Elasticsearch (version 5.4) Server.
In mysql we have a statistik table and a second table with only the first request of a user within a day.
Currently we're using PHP/MySQL to fill that second table and ignore all the other request that are in the statistik table.

The query we're running over the table looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(price_displayed * (query_amount / pricing_unit)) AS `requests`, 
    SUM(price_displayed * (order_amount / pricing_unit)) AS `orders`, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `ts`) AS `date` 
FROM statistics_values
```

The goal is to get rid of the second table.

Is it possible to get only the first document of the day and user and than use a script to calculate the result like in the mysql query?

I tried using a `date_histogramm` aggregation with a `terms` aggregation but it doesn't work.

The Query looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "(client_branch:DE*)"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "created": {
                            "gte": "2017-01-01",
                            "lte": "2017-05-31",
                            "format": "date"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "action": "query"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "type": "enquiry"
                    }
                }   
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "exclude_statistics": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "by_day": {
        "date_histogram": {
          "field": "created",
          "interval": "day"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "by_term": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "user_id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

Any ideas?